# How to: header button style Foursquare (Jquery Mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, header

I would like to add a button to our Jquery Mobile webapp. I added a screenshot from the FourSquare App which show the upperright 'checkin' button and icon, we would love to implement in our HEADER..

http://www.iclarified.com/images/news/26011/99138/99138.png

We can;t figure out how to imlement this. We now the Navbar is able to get us a button style like the FSQ button, but we would ONLY have one of this button's in our Header, aligned right.

Has anybody already designed something like this and could help us?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, here is a quick example:

```
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Foursquare Like</h1>
                <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-d" class="ui-btn-right">Checkin</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>This is a test page</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

See more here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html
jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xWzFt/

Comment: but I would like no buttun like that one. I would love to have it styled like just an icon, as shown in the screenshot. How do I style it that way?

Comment: Design your image or sprite and set it as the background of a `DIV`. Or use `IMG` inside the `DIV`. Then you can place it in the header bar.